# UIPageViewController loads slowly when turning forward, but not backwards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

My `UIPageViewController` shows `UIViewController` views with `UIWebView` as subviews. My problem is, that when I turn forward the `UIWebView` loads slower than when I turn backwards. When turning backwards I instantly see the view of the view controller I want to see, but when turning forward I can see the view of the view controller being white for a short moment before the subview appears.

It is not because the previous pages has been loaded once, because the problem also occurs  when turning forward, backwards and then forward again to the same page.

I am using the exact same methods and classes when loading next and previous pages.

Why does this happen and is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: do you use NSOperationQueue or GCD in your method(s)?

Comment: No, I'm not doing anything asynchronous :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure about this, but i think you net speed can affect this.

Comment: None of the content in the `UIWebView` is loaded from the internet. All the data is local.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to load the data on another thread. Something like:

```
- (void)loadAsynchronousWithMainQueue
{
    NSBlockOperation* blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        //your operations here that do not deal with setting UI elements

        NSBlockOperation* blockWithMainQueue = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        //set UI elements here, on main thread
        }];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:blockWithMainQueue];

    }];

   [operationQueue addOperation:blockOperation];
}
```

Comment: where is "operationQueue" declared?

Comment: the operationQueue can be a Singleton or declared and assigned elsewhere .. you can do it during the ViewController's life cycle or elsewhere